# I can't find what file systems for a USB stick my Android TV supports, wondering how to discover that

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv

I just bought a new Smart TV, FOX 32AOS430E, to be precise and had some issues with it the other night with my USB drive. I needed to put a large movie on the USB drive, over 4 GB, so I formatted it to ext4 and then when I tried to open it in file manager, it says `can't connect to USB`.

So, I reformatted to ExFAT because I read that Android TV supports that format, alas my TV doesn't, or at least my file manager doesn't, and then I try another flash disk in the end that was Fat32 and that one worked.

I can't put my huge movie on FAT32 and can't find anywhere what formats the TV supports, I guess it's not as common as Sony or others, not even a manual online other than what I got in the box.

Edit: I tried ext4, the TV couldn't connect to that one, I have Linux, that's not an issue, but I refuse to believe that Fat32 is the only supported system?

Comment: Official exFat support was introduced about one year ago with Android 13. Before exFat support depended on manufacturer modifications. So on some devices it worked on others not or only partial (e.g read-only).

Comment: You could try using ext3 or ext4 file systems, they are the Linux native filesystems Android devices use most of the time... However Windows doesn't support them, you will need a Linux computer (which is a bit out of scope for this group). File size would not be be an issue.

Comment: Perhaps for additional context, looks like [the TV is running on Android 11](https://www.multicom.me/televizori-i-av-tehnika/led-televizor/fox.html?tags=182).

Comment: Not sure what solution your are looking for.  It is what it is.  You can try and compress (reduce resolution) on the movie